# Sabre REST API OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ get nonstops flights

Tags: api, rest, sabre

I'm using the BFM service in the SABRE REST API. Im trying get only direct flights (Non Stops Flights) using the objects: `TPA_Extensions.DiversityParameters.AdditionalNonStopsPercentage 
TravelPreferences.FlightTypePref.FlightType`

but the answers allways is: `400 Bad Request`

```
{
"status": "NotProcessed",
"type": "Validation",
"errorCode": "ERR.RAF.VALIDATION",
"timeStamp": "2016-02-10T14:24:13+00:00",
"message": "[{\"level\":\"error\",\"schema\":{\"loadingURI\":\"#\",\"pointer\":\"/definitions/org.opentravel.ota._2003._05.OTAAirLowFareSearchRQ.TPAExtensions\"},\"instance\":{\"pointer\":\"/OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ/TPA_Extensions\"},\"domain\":\"validation\",\"keyword\":\"additionalProperties\",\"message\":\"object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\\\"DiversityParameters\\\"]\",\"unwanted\":[\"DiversityParameters\"]}]"
```

}

There are somebody had the same issue?
thanx in advance

Comment: Can you post your request and the endpoint you are using to test?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add `nonnumstop` you must add to `OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ` as in the xml below:

```
<PriceRequestInformation xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10">
<OptionalQualifiers>
  <FlightQualifiers NumStops="0" />
  <PricingQualifiers CurrencyCode="VND">
    <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
  </PricingQualifiers>
</OptionalQualifiers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"DiversityParameters" : {
    "AdditionalNonStopsPercentage" : 20
}
```

or

```
"DiversityParameters" : {
    "AdditionalNonStopsNumber" : 5
}
```

This code works balancing the BFM results.

Comment: Please elaborate and explain why that is to make this a helpful answer.